# Enzyme, test that all checkboxes matching selector are checked

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I tested this:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.my-element').at(1).find('input[type="checkbox"]').at(1).props().checked).toEqual(true);
expect(wrapper.find('.my-element').at(1).find('input[type="checkbox"]').at(2).props().checked).toEqual(true);
expect(wrapper.find('.my-element').at(1).find('input[type="checkbox"]').at(3).props().checked).toEqual(true);
expect(wrapper.find('.my-element').at(1).find('input[type="checkbox"]').at(4).props().checked).toEqual(true);
```

And it works, but in another element there might be more than 4, so I want to do something like

```
expect(wrapper.find('.my-element').at(1).find('input[type="checkbox"]').all().props().checked).toEqual(true);
```

Or something like that. Do I have to make a loop to test all the checkboxes that match? Or is there some built in?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way, don't know if it's the best: but I can make

```
wrapper
      .find('.my-element')
      .at(1)
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .forEach(node => {
        expect(node.props().checked).toEqual(true);
      });
```